# npm install giving me these errors

Tags: node.js, npm, nodes, npm-install

[NPM Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl4oa.png)

Good day guys, I am using my Mac to run npm.
Is there anyone who can help me out with this problem?
I have tried many ways, npm still giving me these errors.

Comment: try using `sudo`

Comment: still getting error:

Comment: drunkiddy@drunkiddy-4 ~ % sudo npm install

Password:

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path /Users/drunkiddy/package.json

npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/drunkiddy/package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent 


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/drunkiddy/.npm/_logs/2022-02-05T19_09_08_363Z-debug-0.log

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this a new project? If so, have you run `npm init`?

Comment: delete `package-lock.json` if exists, run again with sudo before `sudo npm install`

Comment: I have tried both ways, things not getting changed.

Comment: I am trying to run Hashlips Art Engine, nft generator, but its giving errors all the time, is the any there ways to fix it?